# how to get attachment files using union query in ms access

Tags: ms-access, office365, union

I have two independent tables in ms access now i want to get all data from both tables and show as one table using union query.
all is work but the problem is the attachment fields doesn't not loaded and its Empty.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  Table1
UNION ALL select * from Table2;
```

--This is my query which gets all records from both table but the attachment type field is empty

Comment: Try to name the selected fields (instead of SELECT *) and append `.FileName` to the attachment field, e.g., `SELECT YourAttachmentFiledName.FileName FROM Table1`.

Comment: @KostasK. Thank you but I know it just display the name of The file I want to implement search functionality and get the actual file when the user click on  it must open.
Any other method.

Comment: You're probably out of luck. See [here](https://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=82834&p=470228#post470228): 
*Multivalued fields (of which attachment fields are an example) CANNOT be used in UNION queries.
As already suggested, you can create and save the union query then use that in turn to link to the two sets of attachment fields.

OR you can treat this as another reason for not using attachment fields (or any MVFs). Instead store the path to the files and store them outside your database*

Answer (score 0):

This example may be usefull

```
Set rsChild = rsDocs.Fields("DocText").Value
rsChild.Fields("FileData").SaveToFile newFileName
rsChild.Close
```

where rsDocs - ADO (or DAO) recordset as query result
DocText - attachment field name
rsChild.Fields("FileData") - stream object
SaveToFile - method of attachment field

```
rsDocs.Fields("DocText").Value.Fields("FileData").SaveToFile
```

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM  Table1
UNION ALL select * from Table2;
--This is my union Query I have selected all rows from both table but the attachment type field is empty

Comment: I was talking about attachment fields in tables. Where is attachment type field is empty?

Comment: No The Attachment type field has data when I union it they result is empty of attachment field column.

Answer (score 0):

The below example uses an attachment field named `AttachmentField`. You can pass the name of the file you're looking through the parameter.

If you run only the SQL, the parameter window will pop-up asking for the parameter value. To search, find the file and open it, you will need to use VBA.

See an example:

```
PARAMETERS [FileNameParam] Text (255);
SELECT T.ID, T.FileName
FROM (
    SELECT ID, AttachmentField.FileName AS FileName
    FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, AttachmentField.FileName AS FileName
    FROM Table2
) AS T
WHERE T.FileName Like '*' + [FileNameParam] + '*'
```

---

```
Dim q As DAO.QueryDef
Set q = CurrentDb().QueryDefs("Query1")
    q.Parameters("[FileNameParam]").Value = "Blank.pdf"
    
Dim r As DAO.Recordset
Set r = q.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)

'nothing found
If r.EOF Then
    MsgBox "File not found."
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim filepath As String
    filepath = r![FileName]

'open
Application.FollowHyperlink filepath

'clean up
If Not r Is Nothing Then r.Close
If Not q Is Nothing Then q.Close
```